# vowel words using function

Tags: c, arrays, string, function, loops

I have the following task:

1. Create a new text file and name it as `TEXT1.txt`. Write the following content into this text file:

   > Always attend your lecture and tutorial classes

   Using the C programming language

   - Create a function named `vowelwords()`. This function reads the content of `TEXT1.txt` file and prints out on screen the words that do not start with either an uppercase or lowercase vowel (i.e, with ‘a’,’e’,’i’,’o’,’u’).
     For example, if `TEXT1.txt` file contains:

     > Ooi Chee Pun! Always attend your lecture and tutorial classes

     then

     > Chee Pun! your lecture tutorial classes

     will be printed on screen.
     Note: You should determine the appropriate arrays and variables to be used.
   - Write a `main()` function, which calls the created `vowelwords()` function.
2. Modify the `vowelwords()` function in part 1 to write the words that do not start with either an uppercase or lowercase vowel into a new text file called `TEXT2.txt`.

I have done until the following part and my outcome is like:

> lwys ttnd yr lctr nd ttrl clsss

But it should be:

> your lecture tutorial classes

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    FILE *fPtr;
    int c;
    char vowel[50];
    fPtr = fopen("TEXT1.txt","r");
    c = getc(fPtr);
    while(c!= EOF) {
        if((c == 'A')||(c == 'a')||(c == 'E')||(c == 'e')||(c == 'I')||(c == 'i')
         ||(c == 'O')||(c == 'o')||(c == 'U')||(c =='u')){
            c = 0;
        }
        else
            putchar(c);
        c=getc(fPtr);
    }
    fclose (fPtr);
    return 0;
}
```

How do I have to modify the code so that it is working as described in the task?

Comment: Please post the code you have so far and describe the results you've gotten.  (Or is this a "do my homework for me" type question?)

Comment: That's just your assignment. Do you have a specific question about it?

Comment: http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/6166/open-letter-to-students-with-homework-problems

Comment: I have done until this
can anyone please help me to touchup my work

{
    FILE *fPtr;
    int c ;
    char vowel[50];
    fPtr =fopen("TEXT1.txt","r");
    c = getc(fPtr);
    while(c!= EOF) {
        if((c == 'A')||(c == 'a')||(c == 'E')||(c == 'e')||(c == 'I')||(c == 'i')
           ||(c == 'O')||(c == 'o')||(c == 'U')||(c =='u')){
           c = 0;
           }
        else
        putchar(c);
        c=getc(fPtr);
}
    fclose (fPtr);
    return 0;
}

Comment: and the result shwn as lwys ttnd yr lctr nd ttrl clsss

Comment: And for your information it suppose to be "your lecture tutrial classes

Comment: Thanks for the feedback by the way
Bob Brown & Takendarkk

Comment: Post code in your question, not as a comment.

Comment: Takendarkk yes i have done that
And thanks alot for your feedback
Can you please help me on this?

Comment: Sorry guys as the closing date of my assignment still open.
So i cannot post the answer for now to avoid plagiarism.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found the way to solve this. Thanks a lot for your feedback guys.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void vowelwords(){
    FILE *file;
    char line[48];
    file = fopen("TEXT1.txt", "r");
    if (!file)
        return 1;
    fgets(line, 48, file);
    fclose(file);

    char *pch;
    pch = strtok(line, " ,.-");
    while (pch != NULL)
    {
        if (pch[0] == 'a' || pch[0] == 'A' || pch[0] == 'e' || pch[0] == 'E' || pch[0] == 'i'
         || pch[0] == 'I' || pch[0] == 'o' || pch[0] == 'O' || pch[0] == 'u' || pch[0] == 'U')
        {
        }
        else
            printf ("%s ", pch);
        pch = strtok (NULL, " ,.-");
    }
}

int main()
{
    vowelwords();
    return 0;
}
```

And for question 2 the answer is

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
void vowelwords();
int main ()
{
      FILE *file , *fp;
    char line[100];
    file = fopen("TEXT1.txt", "r");
    if (!file)
        return 1;
    fgets(line,100, file);
    fclose(file);
    fp = fopen("TEXT2.txt","w");
    if(fp == NULL){
    printf("Error in opening the file");
        return 1;
}
char * pch;
pch = strtok (line," ,.-");
 while (pch != NULL)
{
if (pch[0] == 'a' || pch[0] == 'A' || pch[0] == 'e' || pch[0] == 'E' || pch[0] == 'i' ||
     pch[0] == 'I' || pch[0] =='o' || pch[0]=='O' || pch[0] == 'u' || pch[0] == 'U'){
}
else
fprintf (fp,"%s ",pch);
pch = strtok (NULL, " ,.-");
}
printf("\n\n\n\n");
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Well done! But let me point out that `return 1;` in a `void` function doesn't make much sense ;)